# How to disable Premailer for individual emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, premailer

We have a couple of instances where we don't want Premailer to process the emails in our rails project.

Is it possible to turn off Premailer for individual triggers? I have tried the following without success:

```
mail :to => user.email, :subject => subject, :premailer => false
```

Answer (score 1):

replace :premailer => false with skip_premailer: true